# Current inside a small segment of conductor having different charges

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

[image]

This image is from [this](https://archive.org/details/classicalelectro0000ross/page/260/mode/1up?view=theater) book by Rosser.
Here in eq$(A4.7)$ author derives the expression,
$$I\mathbf{dl_{1}}=q\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbf{u_{k}}$$
But he assumes that charge $q$ is same. For the general case(where each charge is $q_{i}$) he mentions the eq$(A4.8)$.

When I proceeded to derive the general case I was left with following,
$$I\mathbf{dl_{1}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}\sum_{k=1}^{n}q_{k}$$
How is this equivalent to eq($A4.8$)?

Comment: $u_i$ *is* the speed of the $i^{th}$ charge $q_i$, so  if $q=q_i$ all have the same charge then $\sum_i q_i u_i = q\sum_i u_i$; where is this $q_k$ from ?

Comment: @hyportnex, i was asking for a proof of $Idl=\sum_{i=1}^{n} q_{i}u_{i} $ as the author mentioned that to be generalized version.